# VBA to rename sheet based on filename

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I got a bunch of recorded files in ".Zip" format. My VBA opens all of them and substract the details as text. As there are many the Workbook creates sheets and keeps the count as this:

```
ActiveSheet.Paste
Dim sheetsQuantity As Integer
sheetsQuantity = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet" & sheetsQuantity - 3
```

I need to update the ("Sheet" & quantity) to be the file name that was opened to get the information, and since there are many files each sheet has to match the file.  So, if file #1 is called "MatchCase.zip" I need sheet#1 to be as "MatchCase.zip" and so on.

Any advice, please.

Comment: ....................interesting question................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may depend on your Win version and file structure.  I created a `ZIP` file on my Desktop called *holder.Zip*.  In the folder there is a single file called *formats.xlsm*

I open the file and select some sheet in the workbook and examined `Path` of the workbook using:

```
Sub WhoHoldsMe()
    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = ActiveSheet.Parent.Path
    arr1 = Split(sPath, "\")
    arr2 = Split(arr1(UBound(arr1)), "_")

    MsgBox sPath & vbCrLf & arr2(1)

End Sub
```

I get:

[image]

Clearly the ActiveSheet has a Parent *(the workbook holding the sheet)*.  That workbook has a path that includes the name of the `ZIP` file.
Sadly, the `Path` does not include the information that *holder.zip* resides on my Desktop.